# How to find other basis of polynomials of degree three or less?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How can i find a basis of polynomials of degree three or less, which is other than $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$ ?

Comment: Would $(1+t,t,t^2,t^3)$ do the job?

Comment: various methods: Well know among them are GrahmSchimdt.etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $4\times 4$ invertible matrix $A$ the polynomials
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
p_1(t)\\p_2(t)\\p_3(t)\\p_4(t)
\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}
1\\t\\t^2\\t^3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
constitute a basis.

Answer (score 1):

Any $(P_0, P_1, P_2, P_3)$ with $\deg P_i=i$ will be a basis of polynomials of degree three or less.

Indeed, it is easy to show that such polynomials are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Since this vector space $K[t]_3$ is isomorphic to $K^4$, where $K$ is the field you are taking polynomials over, there is a one-to-one correspondence between bases of $K[t]_3$ and invertible $4\times 4$ matrices over $K$, with the entries in column $k$ giving coefficients of the $k$-th basis polynomial.